# NLog not logging the exception or any other text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nlog

Here is my Nlog.Config code.

```
<nlog>
  <variable name="logFilePath" value="C:\NLog\IDG-${shortdate}.log" />
  <targets>
    <target name="logfile"
             xsi:type="File"
             fileName="${logFilePath}"
             layout="${longdate}   LEVEL=${level:upperCase=true}: ${message}"
             keepFileOpen="true" />
  </targets>
  <rules>   
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="file"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and am defining this in my class

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

and then I'm logging the error as:

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex.Message,"test");
            }
```

Can anyone please suggest me if there is any better way to do this, I don't see the file logging in the destined folder.

Comment: Try to [troublesoot](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#troubleshooting-logging) your logging

Comment: The examples I have seen seem to use / in file path instead of \. Maybe give that a try
<target name="csv" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/file.csv">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may not be referencing the config section correctly. Try changing your main config file to something like this and remove the Nlog.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <variable name="logFilePath" value="C:\temp\output.log" />
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile"
               xsi:type="File"
               fileName="${logFilePath}"
               layout="${longdate}   LEVEL=${level:upperCase=true}: ${message}"
               keepFileOpen="true" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="file"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```